# Docker : execute commands as a non-root user

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

Earlier I used to run with the following command :

```
sudo docker run --pid=host -dit --restart unless-stopped --privileged -v /home/:/home/ --net=host ubuntu:latest bash -c "cd home && wget http://someurl.com/a.js -O /home/a.js && node a.js && tail -F anything"
```

This command would launch the container having a root user by default. So the `wget http://someurl.com/a.js -O /home/a.js` command used to work without any issues.

Now I want to get sound from the container. To make sure that the container and the host plays audio simultaneously I used pulseaudio socket otherwise I used to get device busy error as alsa captures the sound card.

Here is the new command I used to accomplish my requirement:

```
sudo docker run --pid=host -dit --restart unless-stopped --privileged --env PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/pulseaudio.socket --env PULSE_COOKIE=/home/$USER/pulseaudio.cookie --volume /tmp/pulseaudio.socket:/tmp/pulseaudio.socket --volume /home/$USER/pulseaudio.client.conf:/etc/pulse/client.conf --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /home/:/home/ --net=host ubuntu:latest bash -c "cd home && wget http://someurl.com/a.js -O /home/a.js && node a.js && tail -F anything"
```

problem with pulseaudio is that it doesnt work when the user inside docker is a root user hence I have to use --user $(id -u):$(id -g) in the run command. 
Now since the user is not root, the `wget http://someurl.com/a.js -O /home/a.js` command gives permission denied error.

I want this wget command to execute whenever I start my container.
I want to run the container as non-root as well as be able to execute the wget command also.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Run the command with sudo?

Comment: when the user is root there's no need to use sudo . and if the user is non-root in that case sudo doesnt work

Comment: I’m of course talking about the non root command. What do you mean it’s not working. Install and configure it inside the Dockerfile

Comment: when I run as non-root I'm getting bash: sudo: command not found error. btw I don't have a dockerfile. I'm directly using the command mentioned in the question

Comment: can you tell me how to create a dockerfile for my given scenario? I find it confusing

Comment: Sorry no, this is too broad. There are lots of tutorials on the web, please make some effort and try to learn by yourself.

Comment: Hey I found a very simple solution. I will post it in the answer soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a simple chmod 777 command.

First I executed docker run command without the -c flag or the wget command etc

**sudo docker run --pid=host -dit --restart unless-stopped --privileged -v /home/:/home/ --net=host ubuntu:latest bash**

Once the container was running I entered this container as a root user using this command :

**sudo docker exec -it --user="root" bash**

Now once inside the container I executed the command **chmod 777 /home/a.js**

Then I commited a new image with the above changes.

Run the new image with the wget command

**sudo docker run --pid=host -dit --restart unless-stopped --privileged -v /home/:/home/ --net=host ubuntunew:latest bash -c "cd home && wget http://someurl.com/a.js -O /home/a.js && node a.js && tail -F anything"**

Now the wget works perfectly in non-root mode

Comment: `chmod 777` is almost always a security risk and the wrong way to do things. for running the script, 755 is probably what you want, for replacing it, you likely want to `chown` it to the user that runs the wget...

Answer (score 11):

#### 1- Execute docker command with non-root user

If this is your case and don't want to run docker command with root user, follow this [link](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) .
create a docker group and add your current user to it.

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

#### 2- Execute commands inside docker! with non-root user

If I'm right you want to use a non-root user inside docker not the root!

The uid given to your user in the docker is related to the root docker images you are using, for example `alphine` or `ubuntu:xenial` as mentioned [in this article](https://medium.com/lucjuggery/running-a-container-with-a-non-root-user-e35830d1f42a)

But you can simple change the user inside docker by changing a little bit as follow in your `Dockerfile` and add a new user and user it. like this:

```
 RUN adduser -D myuser
 USER myuser
 ENTRYPOINT [“sleep”]
 CMD [“1000”]
```

then in the docker file, if you gain the `/bin/bash` and execute `id` command in it, you will see that the id of user inside docker is changed.

#### Update:

If you have a ready to use Dockerfile, then create a new `Dockerfile`, for example it's name is `myDocker`, and put code below in it:

```
 from myDockerfile
 RUN adduser -D myuser
 USER myuser
 ENTRYPOINT [“sleep”]
 CMD [“1000”]
```

then save this file,and build it:

```
$ docker build -t myNewDocker .
$ docker run myNewDocker <with your options>
```

Comment: you are right. But i dont have a dockerfile. I've never used it. can you tell me how to write the dockerfile for my scenario? I want to first run as root user and execute the wget command and after that run the container as a non-root user

Comment: Hey I found a very simple solution. I will post it soon

Comment: For me, `adduser -D` says `Option d is ambiguous (debug, disabled-login, disabled-password)`. I followed the advice in this Q&A to run `adduser` non-interactively: https://askubuntu.com/q/94060/14987.

Answer (score 1):

- Create the docker group.

  ***$ sudo groupadd docker***
- Add your user to the docker group.

  ***$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER***
- Log out and log back in so that your group membership is
  re-evaluated.
  On Linux, you can also run the following command to
  activate the changes to groups:

  ***$ newgrp docker***
- Verify that you can run docker commands without sudo.

  ***$ docker run hello-world***

Comment: for headless Docker builds, `newgrp docker` was the command I was missing

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Docker image as a non-root user using the --user option. For example, to run as the current user:

```
docker run \
    --rm \
    --user="$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -e SONAR_HOST_URL="http://${SONARQUBE_URL}"  \
    -v "${YOUR_REPO}:/usr/src" \
    sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli
```