# Run Dockerfile Python script as non-root user

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have Dockerfiles with some script, what should I do to run the script as non-root user?

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /
COPY . /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /requirements.txt
CMD ["uvicorn", "api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker : execute commands as a non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54996027/11688567)

Comment: Also have a look at [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `USER` keyword to switch from the default root user.

Before the line with the `RUN`, you can put a line like `USER XXX` with XXX being the wanted user.

(link to doc : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)

Comment: (I'd recommend putting it at the very end, _after_ all of the `RUN` lines.  Doubly true if you `RUN pip install` or something else that needs to affect "system-level" packages inside the image.)

Answer (score 0):

ok I did this by adding

```
RUN groupadd -r user && useradd -r -g user user
USER user
```

before running command